# modrewrite help using multiple dynamic gets

Tags: php, apache2

original = http://ritetag.techreanimate.com/signin.php?network=twitter&fhfghdfghh=sadfgsdf
rewrite = http://ritetag.techreanimate.com/signin/twitter?fhfghdfghh=sadfgsdf

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^signin/([^/]*)$ /signin.php?network=$1
```

i got this working but i cant get other variables using get that come after, how do i get toe rewrite to work for stuff other than network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
    #This rewrite has no L flag so the second one can continue
    #Signin.php can have multiple networks like signin/twitter = signin.php?network=twitter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^signin/([^/]*)$ /signin.php?network=$1 [QSA]

    #this rewrite just allows to use files withouth the .php
    # Like about instead of about.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA]
```